# Convert 2D List to 2D ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, matrix, arraylist

I am trying to convert a 2D List to a 2D ArrayList in Java
I will then convert the 2D ArrayList to a 2D *Array* and implement for loops to return the absolute difference of the 2 diagonals of the matrix.

How would I convert the 2D ArrayList `arr` to a 2D ArrayList?

Here is my work so far in attempting to convert the input List to an ArrayList:

```
    public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {

    //first: 2D List --> 2D ArrayList
    int[][] a = new int[arr.size()][];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> row = arr.get(i);
        a[i] = row.toArray(new int[row.size()]);

    //second: 2D ArrayList --> int[][]

    //third: nested for loop through int[][]to difference between diagonals of 2d array
    }
```

Here is my full code so far.

```
 public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    List<List<Intger>> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    int[][] a = new int[arr.size()][];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> row = arr.get(i);
        a[i] = row.toArray(new int[row.size()]);
    }

        int pri = 0;
        int sec =0;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j <a.length; j++) {

            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                pri += a[i];
            }

            if (i == a.length - j - 1) {
                sec += a[i];
            }

        }
    }
    return Math.abs(pri - sec);

}
```

Comment: `Array[][]` are you sure? what is the waiting output? are you looking for `Integer[][]`

Comment: An `ArrayList` can be created from any `List` using `ArrayList(Collection<?> collection)` constructor (e.g. `ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(arr.get(i));`).

Comment: this is very unclear. first it says "convert a 2D List to a 2D ArrayList", then it says "convert the 2D ArrayList arr to a 2D ArrayList" and in the code there is `int[][]`

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I want to convert the 2D List --> 2D ArrayList --> 2D ARRAY

Comment: yes, @YCF_L, I meant to say that I am looking for int[][]

Comment: why the middle conversion? why not 2D List --> 2D ARRAY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

```
public static int[][] diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
    return arr.stream()
            .map(a -> a.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray())
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: This is converting to Integer object array isnt it? But he is looking for int[][] array ? Both are same ?

Answer (score 1):

This should also work: I tested just now.

row.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

Comment: Good. Failing to test a solution is a good way to get whacked by the mods and reviewers.